# How to print both index of two list in python using nested loop

Tags: python, nested-loops

i'm new to python and i'm still learning it. i really need your help on how to print both index of two list using nested loop in python. for example i want to print both index 0 to index 2 of my 2 list.

Example:

```
List1 = [Ryan, John, Steve, Robert]
List2 = [Anna, Ruby, Ella]
```

Output should be like this:

```
Ryan loves Anna
John loves Ruby
Steve loves Ella
```

then it will ignore the value of 3rd index of List1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: no, it's not what the output i want. and i'm using python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip hanldes list of different sizes just fine:

```
list1 = ['Ryan', 'John', 'Steve', 'Robert']
list2 = ['Anna', 'Ruby', 'Ella']

for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    print(f'{a} loves {b}')
```

Output:

```
Ryan loves Anna
John loves Ruby
Steve loves Ella
```

Comment: thanks sir, it works. but how about if i want a output of 
`Ryan loves Anna

John loves Ruby

Steve loves Ella

Robert is single`

how can i do it with zip?

Comment: to print it in one line you need join: `print(' '.join([f'{a} loves {b}' for a,b in zip(list1, list2)])`